# How to detect the current playing video in the official Youtube app

Tags: android, kotlin, youtube

I want to implement an application that listens for events from the official Youtube Application, I've been digging into a lot of question here in Stackoverflow but I couldn't find a good answer.

I want to listen when a video start and pause/stop, I've seen in the logcat some relevant information. The only thing that is missing is the video ID. But maybe there is another better way to get this information.

[image]

And I know It is possible because that's exactly what Musixmatch does:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: could you please share with us your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to Android **MediaController** (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/media2/session/MediaController) which -

*Allows an app to interact with an active MediaSession or a MediaSessionService which would provide MediaSession. Media buttons and other commands can be sent to the session.*